# How to fuse two time series: one noisy but without gaps, one high-quality but with gaps

Tags: machine-learning, time-series

## Context

To provide some context, I'm working with satellite data and we're trying to relate optical and radar information, which is not straightforward. Previous steps have included the training of a neural network to predict an optical vegetation index (NDVI) based on radar backscatter information, as shown in the figure below. For a few thousands of fields, we trained the network based on the available NDVI recordings by the Landsat 8 (L8) satellite, and the network now predicts such NDVI values based on Sentinel-1 (S1) backscatter (lower panel). Note that the figure below is from a test field that was not included in the training (ensuring its independence).

## Question

Now the real question: the green dots in the figure are output from the neural network and are especially useful in times of high cloudiness, when no optical information is available (blue crosses). But eventually, we need to fuse these time series into one final series that combines the best of both. The optical (blue) one should be the "truth" but is not always available, while the radar (green) one definitely contains uncertainties, but is free of gaps (we can ignore the start of the series here).

Could anyone please guide me in the right direction of how to start tackling this problem? I know it's a quite general question, but I'm not too familiar with time series modelling. I've been looking at GPR, ARMAX, simple regression, but none of them seem the right technique for this issue.
Any ideas of existing tools are greatly appreciated!

## Additional notes

The figure below is just one example. Sometimes, there are many more gaps, sometimes there are almost none. Also the agreement between both time series greatly fluctuates between the different fields, which could all be important elements for the fusion approach.

[image: Time series]